# How does Java runtime find my main class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm

I am learning Spring Boot. I made a simple Spring Boot project that can output a hello world string at http://localhost:8080/welcome

I use Maven to build my project that would output a jar file.
To start up my spring boot app, I use the command as below

```
java -jar my-springboot-app.jar
```

My question is:

How is java smart enough to locate my main class and its main method (e.g. the application launcher)?

I checked the jar file and browsed those BOOT-INF & META-INF and could not find any clues.

Does the spring boot framework (@SpringBootApplication) or maven automatically do the magic for me?

Comment: Look harder. It's specified in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.

Comment: Thanks! Got it! My next question is who generate this MANIFEST.MF ? spring-boot-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of spring boot jar the things are little bit more complicated than regular jar. Mainly because spring boot applicaton jar is not really a JAR (by jar I mean something that has manifest and compiled classes). Regular JARs can be "recognized" and processed by jvm, however in Spring Boot there are also packed dependencies (take a look at `BOOT-INF/lib`) so its jars inside JARs. How to read this?

It turns out that spring boot always has its own main class that is indeed referred to in MANIFEST.MF and this a real entry point of the packaged application.

The manifest file contains the following lines:

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.example.demo.DemoApplication
```

`Main-Class` is a JVM entry point. This class, written by spring developers, basically does two things:
 - Establishes a special class loader to deal with a "non-regular-jar" nature of spring boot application. Due to this special class loaders spring boot application that contains "jars" in `BOOT-INF/lib` can be processed, for example, regular java class loaders apparently cannot do this.
 - Calls the main method of `Start-Class` value. The `Start-Class` is a something unique to spring boot applications and it denotes the class that contains a "main" method - the class you write and the class you think is an entry point :) But from the point of view of the spring boot infrastructure its just a class that has an "ordinary" main method - a method that can be called by reflection.

Now regarding the question "who builds the manifest":

This MANIFEST.MF is usually created automatically by plugins offered by Spring Developers for build systems like Maven or Gradle.

For example, the plugin looks like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

During its work, this plugin identifies your main class (`com.example.demo.DemoApplication` in my example). This class is marked with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation and has a `public static void main` method. 
However, if you put many classes like this the plugin probably won't recognize the correct class so you'll need to configure the plugin properties in POM.xml to specify the right class.

Comment: this helped me to resolve "Error: Could not find or load main class Application" springboot

Answer (score 2):

Java classes are executed within a larger context,
you run java -jar somejar.jar [the class in question will be selected in the .jar file's manifest](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

@SpringBootApplication will have componentscan, enabling auto configuration(autowired)

componentscan - to identify all the controller, service and configuration classes within the package.